# sql sum case not summarising

Tags: sql, sum, case

I'm trying to write a script that summarises the total amount per code per period excluding certain batch types.

The script runs but does not summarise the data per code. What am I doing wrong?

Also welcome feedback if there is a better way to write the script.

Thanks

```
SELECT 
(CASE
    when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominaldr = ''  then det_nominalcr
    when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominalcr = ''  then det_nominaldr
    else  det_analysis
    end ) as Code,
DET_YEAR,
DET_PERIODNUMBR,
sum(CASE
    when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominaldr = ''  then -1* det_nett
    when DET_ledger = 'PL' and det_type = 'CRN'   then -1* det_nett 
        else  det_nett
    end) as Net
FROM SL_PL_NL_DETAIL
where det_year = 'C'
and det_periodnumbr = '07'
and (det_nominalcr like '617%' or det_nominaldr like '617%')
and det_primary not in 
    (select det_primary
     from sl_pl_nl_detail
     where det_ledger in ('PL','SL')
     and det_batch_flag = 1)
group by det_nominaldr, det_nominalcr, det_nett, det_ledger, det_year, det_periodnumbr, det_analysis, det_type
```

Comment: If you just do `SELECT *` and skip the `GROUP BY`, does the result look fine?

Comment: Excluding the sum returns the correct data. However, I need to summarise the data as the database contains almost 1m transcations for this year.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need det_nett column in Group by clause Try this

```
     SELECT 
(CASE
    when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominaldr = ''  then det_nominalcr
    when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominalcr = ''  then det_nominaldr
    else  det_analysis
    end ) as Code,
DET_YEAR,
DET_PERIODNUMBR,
sum(CASE
    when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominaldr = ''  then -1* det_nett
    when DET_ledger = 'PL' and det_type = 'CRN'   then -1* det_nett 
        else  det_nett
    end) as Net
FROM SL_PL_NL_DETAIL
where det_year = 'C'
and det_periodnumbr = '07'
and (det_nominalcr like '617%' or det_nominaldr like '617%')
and det_primary not in 
    (select det_primary
     from sl_pl_nl_detail
     where det_ledger in ('PL','SL')
     and det_batch_flag = 1)
group by det_nominaldr, det_nominalcr,  det_ledger, det_year, 
      det_periodnumbr, det_analysis, det_type
```

Comment: Hi.   Sadly removing det_nett means that not all data is included in the resulting sum.

Comment: But you are summing the column and including it in group by as well which seems incorrect

Answer (score 0):

In case this is Oracle, since you did not specify your DBMS, try this (in oracle you can easily mention the case in group by, I am not sure about other databases):

```
SELECT 
(CASE
    when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominaldr = ''  then det_nominalcr
    when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominalcr = ''  then det_nominaldr
    else  det_analysis
    end ) as Code,
DET_YEAR,
DET_PERIODNUMBR,
sum(CASE
    when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominaldr = ''  then -1* det_nett
    when DET_ledger = 'PL' and det_type = 'CRN'   then -1* det_nett 
        else  det_nett
    end) as Net
FROM SL_PL_NL_DETAIL
where det_year = 'C'
and det_periodnumbr = '07'
and (det_nominalcr like '617%' or det_nominaldr like '617%')
and det_primary not in 
    (select det_primary
     from sl_pl_nl_detail
     where det_ledger in ('PL','SL')
     and det_batch_flag = 1)
group by CASE  when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominaldr = ''  then det_nominalcr  
               when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominalcr = ''  then det_nominaldr
               else  det_analysis  end,
         DET_YEAR,
         DET_PERIODNUMBR
```

Comment: Sorry - this is using Access Dimensions database

Comment: ANSI SQL does not allow case expressions in the GROUP BY, only columns. The solution is to use a derived table (see my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Save some typing by wrapping your original query up in a derived table, `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select Code, DET_YEAR, DET_PERIODNUMBR, SUM(Net)
FROM
(
    SELECT (CASE
            when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominaldr = ''  then det_nominalcr
            when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominalcr = ''  then det_nominaldr
            else  det_analysis
            end) as Code,
           DET_YEAR,
           DET_PERIODNUMBR,
           (CASE
            when DET_ledger = 'NL' and det_nominaldr = ''  then -1* det_nett
            when DET_ledger = 'PL' and det_type = 'CRN'   then -1* det_nett 
            else  det_nett
            end) as Net
    FROM SL_PL_NL_DETAIL
    where det_year = 'C'
      and det_periodnumbr = '07'
      and (det_nominalcr like '617%' or det_nominaldr like '617%')
      and det_primary not in 
        (select det_primary
         from sl_pl_nl_detail
         where det_ledger in ('PL','SL')
         and det_batch_flag = 1)
) dt
group by Code, DET_YEAR, DET_PERIODNUMBR
```